# Clojure: How to apply a function to every value in a nested map and update?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, nested

Let's say there is a nested map like below: (partially nested only)

```
(def mymap {:a 10
        :b {:ba 21, :bb 22 :bc 23}
        :c 30
        :d {:da 41, :db 42}})
```

How can I apply a function, say `#(* % 2)`, and update every value in this map? That is without specifying any key. The result will look like this:

```
{:a 20, 
 :b {:ba 42, :bb 44, :bc 46}, 
 :c 60, 
 :d {:da 82, :db 84}}
```

So far, I came up with this own function:

```
(defn map-kv [f coll] (reduce-kv (fn [m k v] (assoc m k (f v))) (empty coll) coll))
```

But I still need to specify a first-level key and can't apply to all first-level and second-level keys values.

Comment: You were close. Simply needed to add a condition and a recursive call: `(defn map-kv [f coll] (reduce-kv (fn [m k v] (if (map? v) (assoc m k (map-kv f v)) (assoc m k (f v)))) (empty coll) coll))`. But the solution by @alan-thompson is definitely simpler/idiomatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to postwalk, as Alan mentioned, it is trivial to recursively explore the map and update every key.  Clojure provides a function called `fmap` that simply applies a function to every value in a map.  To use:

In project.clj, declare this dependency:

```
[org.clojure/algo.generic "0.1.2"]
```

And in your code, then require:

```
(require '[clojure.algo.generic.functor :as f :only [fmap]])
```

Then define a function that will walk your map recursively:

```
(defn fmap*
  [f m]
  (f/fmap #(if (map? %)
             (fmap* f %)
             (f %))
          m))

(fmap*
   (partial * 2) ;; double every number
   {:a 21 :b {:x 11 :y 22 :z {:p 100 :q 200}}})
=> {:a 42, :b {:x 22, :y 44, :z {:p 200, :q 400}}}
```

In case you don't want to have to include a non-core function, here's the code for fmap used on a map, from the [clojure source](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/generic/functor.clj#L33) (adapted for a defn):

```
(defn fmap [f m]
  (into (empty m) (for [[k v] m] [k (f v)])))
```

Comment: This won't work.  Your `f/fmap` trips in the context of `[f m]`.

Answer (score 8):

You may wish to review the `postwalk` function:  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk

```
(def data
   {:a 10
    :b {:ba 21, :bb 22 :bc 23}
    :c 30
    :d {:da 41, :db 42}} )

(defn tx-nums [x]
  (if (number? x)
    (* 2 x)
    x))

(postwalk tx-nums data) => 
  {:a 20, 
   :b {:ba 42, :bb 44, :bc 46}, 
   :c 60, 
   :d {:da 82, :db 84}}
```

---

Porthos3 makes a good point.  The above will transform map keys as well as map values.  If you want only values to change, you could use the `map-vals` function from [the Tupelo Clojure library](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.core.html#var-map-vals) (the Medley lib [has a similar function](https://weavejester.github.io/medley/medley.core.html#var-map-vals)).

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [clojure.walk :as walk]))

(dotest
  (let [data-2     {1 2
                    3 4}
        tx-vals-fn (fn [item]
                     (if (map? item)
                       (t/map-vals item #(* 2 %))
                       item))
        result     (walk/postwalk tx-vals-fn data-2)]
    (is= (spyx result) {1 4, 3 8})))
```

with result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
result => {1 4, 3 8}

Ran 2 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

Comment: Your input data is incorrect in your sample. I think you accidentally copied the output.

Comment: This also applies the function to map keys. If data is {1 2, 3 4} it will return {2 4, 6 8} instead of {1 4, 3 8}.

Answer (score 2):

I really like specter, see https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter

If you exactly want to change the top 2 levels, calling transform twice is the simplest

```
(->> mymap 
     (sp/transform [sp/MAP-VALS map? sp/MAP-VALS number?] #(* 2 %))
     (sp/transform [sp/MAP-VALS number?] #(* 2 %)))
```

You can implement the walk part in specter too, if you really want to replace everything recursively. For example, I wanted to floatify all numbers in an arbitrary structure. First, I had to define the walker (which also handles vectors, seq, and sets). This is generic, so I can reuse it.

```
 (defprotocolpath WalkValues)

 (extend-protocolpath WalkValues
                 clojure.lang.IPersistentVector [ALL WalkValues]
                 clojure.lang.IPersistentMap [MAP-VALS WalkValues]
                 clojure.lang.IPersistentSet [ALL WalkValues]
                 clojure.lang.ISeq [ALL WalkValues]
                 Object STAY)
```

but once I done that, I can implement it is

```
 (sp/transform [sp/WalkValues integer?] float mymap)
```

or in this example

```
 (sp/transform [sp/WalkValues number?] #(* 2 %) mymap)
```

Comment: `CTRL-f "specter"`. Yep! And nice example of implementing a walker.

Answer (score 0):

```clj
(require '[clojure.walk :as walk])

(defn fmap [f m]
  (into (empty m) (for [[k v] m] [k (f v)])))

(defn map-leaves
  [f form]
  (walk/postwalk (fn [m]
                   (if (map? m)
                     (fmap #(if (map? %) % (f %)) m)
                     m))
                 form))
```

example:

```clj
(map-leaves
 (partial * 2)
 {:a 10
  :b {:ba 21, :bb 22 :bc 23}
  :c 30
  :d {:da 41, :db 42}})
;; {:a 20, :b {:ba 42, :bb 44, :bc 46}, :c 60, :d {:da 82, :db 84}}
```

explanation:

`postwalk` calls `walk` in its implementation.

```clj
(defn postwalk
  [f form]
  (walk (partial postwalk f) f form))
```

`walk` checks the type of the form and it matches the form (a map) against `coll?` and then maps inner (which is postwalk with f) against the form which matches `map-entry?`.

We don't want to "postwalk with f" against the key so we check to see if it's a map and skip it (return m) if it's not a map. (This logic fails if you use a map as a key.)

`postwalk` passed our `f` into `walk` as `outer`. The lambda inside map-leaves skips calling `outer` (aka `f`) on the resulting maps (look at the `coll?` match) as it backs out of the recursion. The maps were already transformed by the `map inner`.

```clj
(defn walk
  [inner outer form]
  (cond
    (list? form)      (outer (apply list (map inner form)))
    (map-entry? form)
    (outer (MapEntry. (inner (key form)) (inner (val form)) nil))
    (seq? form)       (outer (doall (map inner form)))
    (record? form)    (outer (reduce (fn [r x] (conj r (inner x))) form form))
    (coll? form)      (outer (into (empty form) (map inner form)))
    :else             (outer form)))
```